# Im trying to get calculate two tkinter entries with a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried StringVar, I've tried set().
Note: The program successfully calculates the value and returns the answer in a seperate pop-up, but I would like it to display the answer in the readonly "yards" entry field as well.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

#Formats all of the visible elements of the tkninter GUI.Connects the buttons to their functions.
class MetersToYardsApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):



        topLevel = ttk.Frame(parent, padding=10)
        topLevel.grid(column=0, row=0)

        headerLabel = ttk.Label(topLevel, text="Meters to Yards Calculator", font="{Arial} 16 {bold}")
        headerLabel.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")

        inputFrame = ttk.Frame(topLevel, padding=10)
        inputFrame.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nsew")

        metersLabel = ttk.Label(inputFrame, text="Meters:")
        yardsLabel = ttk.Label(inputFrame, text="Yards:")

        metersEntry = ttk.Entry(inputFrame)
        yardsEntry = ttk.Entry(inputFrame, state="readonly")

        metersLabel.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="e")
        yardsLabel.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="e")

        metersEntry.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=3)
        yardsEntry.grid(column=1, row=1, pady=3)

        buttonFrame = ttk.Frame(topLevel)
        buttonFrame.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky='nsew')

        clearButton = ttk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Clear", command=self.clear)
        okayButton = ttk.Button(buttonFrame, text="Calculate", command=self.calculate)
        clearButton.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=3)

        okayButton.grid(column=1, row=0)



        self.mainWindow = topLevel

        self.metersEntry = metersEntry
        self.yardsEntry = yardsEntry


    #Clear Button
    def clear(self):
        # print("Clear")
        self.metersEntry.delete(0, tk.END)
    #Formats the Pop-up that displays the answer
    def showAnswer(self, parent, text):



        rootFrame = ttk.Frame(parent, padding=10)
        rootFrame.grid(column=0, row=0)

        headerLabel = ttk.Label(rootFrame, text="The Answer", font="{Arial} 14 {bold}")
        headerLabel.grid(column=0, row=0)

        answerLabel = ttk.Label(rootFrame, text=text, justify=tk.CENTER)
        answerLabel.grid(column=0, row=1)


    #Performs Calculations if input is valid.
    def calculate(self):
        # print("Calculate Meters: ", self.metersEntry.get())
        try:
            meters = float(self.metersEntry.get())
            yards = meters * 1.094


        except:
            top2 = tk.Toplevel(self.mainWindow)
            self.showAnswer(top2, "There was an Error.\n" + "Please Enter a Valid Number for Meters")
            # print("Please Enter a Valid Number for Meters.")
            return

        

        print(meters, "Meters is ", yards, "Yards. ")
        top2 = tk.Toplevel(self.mainWindow)





        self.showAnswer(top2, str(meters) + " Meters is equivalent to " + "{:.2f} Yards.".format(yards))

        return float(yards)
```

Comment: Please see [ask]

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and make sure you understand how to post code so that it shows up neatly, preserving the indentation (since that is crucial in Python). Don't just show the code and describe a goal; make sure to **ask a specific question** - it should start with a question word like "why" or "how", and end with a question mark (`?`).

Comment: Telling us "I have tried StringVar, I've tried set()" is not helpful; please show us *how* you tried them, explain *what happened* when you tried them, and explain *how that is different* from what is supposed to happen. Also, please read [mre], and avoid showing more code than necessary. Especially for Tkinter examples, try to include only the code needed for the GUI widgets that are involed in the problem.

Comment: The specific question is how do I set a tkinter entry field to a value that is calculated by my program. Be advised, the program already return the answer in a separate tkinter popup window, but for my sanity, I need to learn why I cannot get it to return the value in the entry field as well. Apologies for the messy code, when I try to set the value to the field, I get: Unresolved attribute reference 'set' for class 'Entry' . Though Tkinter entry surely does have a set(). Here is a replit with the solutions I have tried currently: https://replit.com/join/lsgspeiguv-kidpresident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to use DoubleVar to update the Entry element:

```
yards_entry_var = tk.DoubleVar(inputFrame, 0)
```

Then you should place it inside the Entry element 'textvariable':

```
yardsEntry = ttk.Entry(inputFrame, textvariable=yards_entry_var, state="readonly")
```

to use it outside the init function:

```
self.yards_entry_var = yards_entry_var
```

in the calculate function, after calculating the yards:

```
self.yards_entry_var.set(yards)
```

And finally, when you want to clear the value in the clear function:

```
self.yards_entry_var.set(0)
```